# Eigenfunctions of angular momentum operators in momentum representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, eigenvalue

I want to know the eigenfunctions of $L^2$ and $L_z$ in the momentum representation. Do I need to Fourier transform the spherical harmonics?

Comment: Since $\mathbf{L}=\mathbf{x}\times\mathbf{p}$, it could be written in momentum representation as the operator $i\hbar\mathbf{p}\times\nabla$ for $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ functions of the momentum coordinates. It differs by just a minus sign from the operator in the position representation, so maybe it's just a matter of renaming the variables and changing some signs.

Comment: Actually I got the sign wrong: it's $\mathbf{L}=-\mathbf{p}\times\mathbf{x}=-i\hbar\mathbf{p}\times\nabla$, so it really comes down to renaming the variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on [yellowquark](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/36254/yellowquark)'s comment in the OP, we can explicitly show this by computing the Fourier transform of a 3D wave function.

$$\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$$
We assume a wave function of the form
$$
\psi\left(  \vec{r}\right)  =f\left(  r\right)  Y_{\alpha,\beta}\left(
\Omega_{\vec{r}}\right)  .
$$
The Fourier transform of this wave function is given by
$$
\tilde{\psi}\left(  \vec{k}\right)  =\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\int d^{3}r\left[ e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec
{r}} f\left(  r\right)  Y_{\alpha,\beta}\left(
\Omega_{\vec{r}}\right) \right] .
$$
We expand the complex exponential [in spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_wave_expansion#Expansion_in_spherical_harmonics) as
$$
e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}=4\pi\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-l}^{l}e^{-i\pi
l/2}j_{l}\left(  kr\right)  Y_{l,m}\left(  \Omega_{\vec{k}}\right)
Y_{l,m}^{\ast}\left(  \Omega_{\vec{r}}\right)  ,
$$
where $j_{l}\left(  kr\right)  $ is a spherical Bessel function, and write
\begin{align*}
\tilde{\psi}\left(  \vec{k}\right)    & =\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}} \int r^{2}dr\int d\Omega_{\vec{r}
}\left\{
%replacing the expansion
\left[
4\pi\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\sum
_{m=-l}^{l}e^{-i\pi l/2}j_{l}\left(  kr\right)  Y_{l,m}\left(  \Omega_{\vec{k}
}\right)  Y_{l,m}^{\ast}\left(  \Omega_{\vec{r}}\right) 
\right]
%the functiont we want to find the Fourier transform of
f(r) Y_{\alpha,\beta}\left(
\Omega_{\vec{r}}\right)  \right\}\\
%%next line
& =\frac{4\pi}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\sum
_{m=-l}^{l}\left\{e^{-i\pi l/2}Y_{l,m}\left(  \Omega_{\vec{k}}\right)  \int dr \left[r^{2} f(r)
j_{l}\left(  kr\right) \right] \int d\Omega_{\vec{r}}\left[Y_{l,m}^{\ast}\left(
\Omega_{\vec{r}}\right)  Y_{\alpha,\beta}\left(  \Omega_{\vec{r}}\right) \right]\right\} .
\end{align*}
Using the orthogonality relation for the spherical harmonics, this becomes
\begin{align*}
\tilde{\psi}\left(  \vec{k}\right)    & =\frac{4\pi}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-l}^{l}\left\{e^{-i\pi l/2}
Y_{l,m}\left(  \Omega_{\vec{k}}\right) \delta_{\alpha,l}\delta_{\beta,m} 
\int dr \left[r^{2}f(r)j_{l}\left(  kr\right)\right]
\right\}\\
& =Y_{\alpha,\beta}\left(  \Omega_{\vec{k}}\right)  e^{-i\pi\alpha/2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int dr \left[r^{2}f(r)j_{\alpha}\left(  kr\right)\right].
\end{align*}

We can see directly that we get the same spherical harmonic out, now just a function of the angular variables of the momentum rather than position.

Comment: Can you explain the last step a bit more? It seems like I am missing something obvious but I don't see what is those $L,\alpha$ and how you performed the sum over $l,m$.

Comment: @DvijD.C. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Orthogonality_and_normalization) or any text that discusses spherical harmonics. These functions form an orthonormal set with the proper weight function.  Any quantum mechanics or electromagnetism text is likely to cover these in some detail.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the bother. :P I was looking from phone and the weird display just hid those deltas with $L,\alpha$ in the second last step. So I was super confused as to how those $L,\alpha$ came out of thin air xD It's all clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The Fourier transforms of the spatial representations are the momentum space representations. Don't forget to include the radial wave function when doing do.