# Is there a momentum representation of the atomic stationary states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, fourier-transform, atoms, orbitals

In standard quantum mechanics, the atomic orbitals are represented by the following wave functions (where $u = 2 \mathrm{Z} r / n a$):
$$\tag{1}
\psi_{n l m}(r, \theta, \varphi) = \phi_{n l}(r) \, Y_{l m}(\theta, \varphi) = N_{n l} \, u^l \, e^{- \frac{1}{2} \, u} \, L_{n - l - 1}^{2 l + 1}(u) \, Y_{l m}(\theta, \varphi),
$$
with the usual quantum numbers: $n = 1, 2, 3, \dots$, $l = 0, 1, 2, \dots, n -1$ and $m = 0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \dots, \pm l$.  Here, $\phi_{n l}(r)$ is the *radial* wave function.

Is there a ***momentum space*** representation of the radial wave function $\phi_{n l}(r)$ (or maybe the complete wave function (1)), something like $\tilde{\phi}_{n l}(p)$?  AFAIK, I never saw this in the usual QM books, while it is frequently shown for the free particle and other cases.

Comment: [Wave functions of the Hydrogen atom in the momentum representation](https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.13989v2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was apparently done by [Podolsky and Pauling in 1929](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.34.109).  Some of the details below are taken from this paper.  I also found [this comment](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.12509.pdf) on another paper that has these details in a more modern notation, but I can't tell if it was actually published or not so cannot comment on its veracity. There is also [this reference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.13989v2.pdf), whose purpose is to construct momentum-space wave functions according to a *radial* momentum operator. The Podolsky-Pauling reulst can be found on Pp. 6-8 of this paper, but other representations and interpretations can be found therein.

---

The momentum space representation of the hydrogen orbitals can be arrived at follows. First of all, see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/291674/83835), which shows that the Fourier transform of a wave function of the form
$$
\psi\left(  \vec{r}\right)  =f\left(  r\right)  Y_{\alpha,\beta}\left(
\Omega_{\vec{r}}\right)\,,
$$
is given by
\begin{align*}
\tilde{\psi}\left(  \vec{k}\right)
& =Y_{\alpha,\beta}\left(  \Omega_{\vec{k}}\right)  e^{-i\pi\alpha/2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int dr\,r^{2}f(r)j_{\alpha}\left(  kr\right).
\end{align*}
The remaining part of the transform, provided I've transcribed things correctly, is given by
$$
\int dr\,r^{2}R_{nl}(r)j_{\alpha}\left(  kr\right)
=
\frac{\pi 2^{2l+4}l!}{(\gamma h)^{3/2}}
\left(\frac{n(n-l-1)!}{(n+l)!}\right)^{1/2}
\frac{\zeta^l}{(\zeta^2 +1)^{l+2}}
C_{n-l-1}^{l+1}\left(\frac{\zeta^2-1}{\zeta^2+1}\right)
\,,
$$
where
\begin{align}
\zeta &= \frac{2\pi}{\gamma h}p\,,\\
\gamma &= \frac{4\pi^2\mu e^2Z}{n h^2}=\frac{Z}{na_0}\,,\\
p &= \hbar k\,,
\end{align}
and the $C$ functions are [Gegenbauer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gegenbauer_polynomials) [functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/search/search?q=Gegenbauer%20function). The quantity $Z$ is the atomic number, and so $Z=1$ for hydrogen.

Given changes in notation and conventions for special functions over the years. It's possible that the expression I've written down is not precisely correct.

Comment: The shape of the radial function is deceiving!  It's very complicated, no wonder it isn't shown in most QM textbooks...

Comment: @Cham When I plot the first few of these functions, the curves look rather simple. Can you elaborate on what you meant by your comment?

Comment: Could you add a few of these plots in your answer?  It could be interesting.  But the analytical expression is complicated (how are defined these $C_p^q$?).  It could also be interesting to get the explicit function for the **ground state**, with the Fourier decomposition made explicit too (on which functions does $\psi_{100}(r)$ is decomposed).

Comment: @Cham I provided linker to the Gegenbauer polynomials/functions (the $C$'s). They're really not more mysterious than the Laguerre polynomials/functions used for the position-space representations of the hydrogenic wave functions. And I don't see the momentum-space representations of the radial parts of the wave function as being all that more complicated than the position-space ones, especially when you include the explicit expressions for the normalization factors $N_{nl}$. In *Mathematica*, $C_{n-l-1}^{l+1}(x)$ is `GegenbauerC[n-l-1, l+1], x]`, so easily plotted.

Comment: @Cham I provided that link too. There are two links when I write "Gegenbauer functions", not one!

Comment: Hum, yeah, the links work, but it wasn't obvious that it was two different links.  I suggest that you edit the links to state that one is from Wikipedia.

Comment: Using your method, are you able to find analytical expressions for the average **radial momentum** $\langle \, p \, \rangle$ and $\langle \, p^2 \rangle$?  The radial average $\langle \, p \, \rangle$ should be 0, though.

Comment: And what explicit radial function $\tilde{\psi}_{100}(\vec{k})$ do you get for the ground state?

Comment: @Cham The radial part of the ground state looks like $(1+(k a_0)^2)^{-2}$, up to some constant factors.  I haven't computed any of the expectation values, but now that you have the explicit expressions, you can do it yourself!  Use Mathematica or some other computing software if you can't do it by hand. By the way, if you want things in terms of the *radial* momentum, then I'm not sure that these wave functions are the ones you want.  You might check the third reference I provided in my post, which is the same as the link provided by Ghoster in your OP.